# sql in android-Hebrew

Tags: android, sql, hebrew

I defined a sql table:

```
      ...

        customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 86, 'This ', 'זה ');");
        customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 87, 'most ', 'ביותר ');");
        customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 88, 'use ', 'uu ');");


.....


    }
    catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create records");
    }
}
```

I initialize it on "onCreate":

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        customersDB2 =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(  DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);


        customersDB2.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_NAME +
                " (Block INT," +
                " Name VARCHAR, Street VARCHAR);");
        mFillDbsTable();}
    catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "create/Open the database problem");


    }
```

My problem is that c.moveToFirst() always return false. This problem fixed when I change the Hebrew to English. I could I fix it?

```
    Cursor c = customersDB2.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM "    +
            TABLE_NAME +" where Block == 88", null);


    if (c != null ) { // this return true

        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {  //this return false
            do {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"null1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                 street = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Street"));

                 results.add(name + ", " + street );
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

The log is empty.

Answer (score 0):

after the running oncreate.
check the table using "sqlite manager" or another tool,
to see if the table actually containes the rows you are expecting to get